# Choosing the correct Amazon Machine Image (AMI) for bash script upload to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a bash script written for OSX that downloads many large .zip files, unpacks them, and writes the contents to a Postgres database.

I want to do this from an EC2 instance because the operation takes a long time.

I don't which AMI to choose, given that OSX is not an option.

Should I be doing this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an AMI you can use AWS cloud init for launching your bash script after your instance is launched and as far as operating is concerned i think any operating system is capable for doing things you mentioned in the question however, i would recommend to use **Amazon linux** because its more optimized for ec2